# How does the CPU knows which interrupt service routine to run against a hardware interrupt?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu, interrupt

For example, a key on a keyboard is press causing a hardware interrupt to be generated to the CPU, the CPU sends an acknowledgement to the interrupt controller. At the stage of the interrupt process, how does the CPU knows which interrupt service routine to run based on a key press on the keyboard?

Comment: After the CPU acks the interrupt, an interrupt controller (PIC) will send the interrupt number back to the CPU. CPU then uses that interrupt number as an index into the interrupt vector table to find the appropriate handler and then continues from there.

Comment: See also http://wiki.osdev.org/Interrupts

Comment: @MichaelPetch - In the case of early PC's that used or were based on 8259A type interrupt chips, there are two interrupt acknowledges (INTA). The first INTA updates interrupt state, but doesn't drive the data bus, the second INTA results in the interrupt number being written to the data bus. I assume that later chipsets dropped full 8259 emulation and send out the interrupt number on the first INTA.

Comment: note different architectures and processor designs work differently (x86 vs mips vs arm vs etc).  they generally fall into one of two or three categories, either a mass of separate interrupt lines one per vector.  a single or few interrupts into the core, with a controller on the other side of that allows for and muxes in many individual interrupts.  and in the latter case it is either hardware or software that asks the interrupt controller who caused the interrupt.

Comment: and of course after all of that you can still have a chip/board design that further multiplexes an interrupt line where ideally software would have to go interrogate that implementation to find out who caused it, sometimes you have to interrogate a list of peripherals to find out who.

Comment: @rcgldr Modern Intel processors receive interrupt requests over the DMI bus from the PCH. If the PIC is being used, and that's unlikely these days, the PCH internally goes through the motions of the two INTA cycles (at least according the documentation) but I don't think this is visible to the CPU. If the APIC is being used, pretty much a requirement for any mulit-core system, then the IOAPIC on the PCH communicates with a local APIC on one of the CPU cores through normal device memory writes with any acknowledgement cycle.

Comment: @rcgldr : I didn't get into the specifics as it was a general comment and the actual physical mechanism used may be different and emulated (or a different mechanism used altogether). But yes usually the CPU had to signal(pulse) on INTA twice. The first one would  allow the PIC to set the priority ISR bit and its associated IRR bit. During the second INTA pulse it would place the interrupt index onto the data bus.

Comment: @MichaelPetch - Since the 8259 had/has two modes, 8080/8086 modes, where 8080 mode involves 3 INTA's with the 8259 generating an 8080 call instruction sequence, and 8086 mode involves two INTA's, I'm wondering if the reason for the 8086's two INTA's was due to speed or clock edge count limitations with the original 8259 chips

Comment: Thanks but I still have the question, how does the CPU knows which Interrupt Service Routine to run based on a key being pressed on a keyboard on an x86 Intel CPU. I mean, is their a mapping between the Interrupt number and the ISR? If so, what is it called?

Comment: Assuming legacy interrupts - when the BIOS starts up the PICs are set to a default mapping where IRQ0- IRQ7 are mapped to interrupt vector 0x08 through 0x0f on the PC. IRQ8-IRQ15 are mapped to interrupt vector 0x70 to 0x77. You can remap the PICs to have a different base. Most OS developers remap them anyway since IRQ8-15 overlap the reserved interrupt list.Based on the above, by default IRQ0 (system timer) is interrupt vector 0x08, IRQ1 (keyboard) is interrupt vector 0x09.